# How to use Button.KeyPress in vb

Tags: vb.net

what I can do to execute Button.KeyPress event in vb ?

for example 
Button.Click , should I press the button , so what about Button.KeyPress

Comment: Not sure I follow.  You click the button to trigger the Click() event.  To trigger the KeyPress() event, you press a key while the Button has focus.  Or are you asking how to make it fire at run-time via code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Runtime, in order to get the `KeyPress` event to fire, the Button needs to be first be selected, then press a (keyboard) button.

The `KeyPress` is normally used for things like a `Textbox`, it's not normally used with a `Button`

If you are looking for a way to force the `Button.Click` event, you can always call `Me.Button1.PerformClick()`